# SSL Seafile and SSL Gitlab Apache Forwarding Problems

Tags: git, apache, ssl, https, gitlab

I´ve set up apache files for my 2 SSL Services(seafile and gitlab subdomain). Both are defined via dnsmasq and simply point on the own server ip.
I´ve two config files in /etc/apache2/sites-available(one for gitlab and one for seafile). **Each service runs good for themselves** . But if I enable the other config, there occurs a 404 error.The apache redirects me then from https://seafile.mlnet.de to http://seafile.mlnet.de/users/sign_in (<-- /users/sign_in is the default gitlab login page).I don´t know the **cause** of this forwarding to **Port 80**. If I enable **only seafile**, I can access the Login Page(domain.de/accounts/login/?next=/) via the **gitlab** subdomain.

I would be grateful for assistance.

Here are my apache config files:

**GIT_SSL.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:TLSv1:+HIGH:!SSLv2:!MD5:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!ADH:!eNULL:!aNULL
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key


ServerName gitlab.mlnet.de/
DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
ServerSignature Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Location />
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:7777
ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.mlnet.de/
</Location>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:7777%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

**SEAFILE_SSL.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName seafile.mlnet.de/
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            Alias /media /home/seafile/haiwen/seafile-server-latest/seahub/media

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


            SSLEngine on


            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key


            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>


            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

            BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown


RewriteEngine On

  ProxyPass /seafhttp http://127.0.0.1:8082
  ProxyPassReverse /seafhttp http://127.0.0.1:8082

  RewriteRule ^/seafhttp - [QSA,L]


  RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seahub.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens if you use different ports for each service?